# Espresso Android matching textviews inside parent

Tags: java, android, automated-tests, android-testing, android-espresso

I have a simple linear layout with two textviews inside it. The linear layout has an unique id but the textviews don't have. How do I verify one of the texts is  from those textviews?

I tried the following code:

```
 onView(allOf(NavigationDrawerComponent.topSectionWrapper,
                hasSibling(withClassName(Matchers.equalTo(TextView.class.getSimpleName())))))
                .check(matches(withText(Data.fullUserName)));
```

Unfortunately,its not working for me.I am getting the following error:

```
   android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in
    hierarchy found matching
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [hasDescendant()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers.html#hasDescendant(org.hamcrest.Matcher%3Candroid.view.View%3E))

```
onView(withId(R.id.recycler_view)).check(matches(atPosition(0, hasDescendant(withText("Available")))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you may want to scroll the `RecyclerView` until you find the right child view (if the view is not visible, it is probably not yet created). In that case using `scrollTo` is not enough and Android Studio will not recommend a better choice automatically. You have to do this:

```
 onView(withId(R.id.recycler_view))
 .perform(RecyclerViewActions.scrollTo(hasDescendant(withText("Available"))));
```